# Laravel 5.5 exception handle custom view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, laravel-5.5

In App\Exceptions\Handler I'd like to return a custom view depending of which HTTP status codes I get.

I'd like to do something like, *if statuscode == 404 return 404 view* etc but I can't find the proper syntax, and I start wondering if the Handler Class is the right place to do this.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if (App::environment('local')) {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    // what do I do here ?

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can provide your own **Blade** templates that should be used to render error pages for different status codes.

E.g. for 404 error put your template in **resources/views/errors/404.blade.php**.

You can find more info in the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Comment: I already created my blades but I don't know how to set them by default when I got an error

Comment: You don't need to do anything, just keep the default implementation of Handler::render(). Every HttpException thrown should then use the provided template.

Comment: how to get a message like `page expired` for `419` (not specific error)??. `$exception->getMessage()` give the specific error